# General SSLEngine error in Neo4j

Tags: ssl, neo4j

I am running a Java Neo4j driver and have this :

```
  Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.basic( "neo4j", "poassword" ) ); 
  Session session = driver.session();
```

when executing the last line, it will throw an error:

> "General SSLEngine problem"

It worked for `Neo4j 3.0.0` but after upgrading to `3.0.1` it is giving this error.
Please help ...

Comment: Report it to Neo. It's a bug in their driver.

Answer (score 4):

Try to delete the entry from known_hosts file for your server (ex: localhost).
This file is located in the users folder.